# How can I automatically extract specific regions of a video frame every second to image files

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to extract specific chryons from videos of Overwatch games so I can OCR them and store stats. How can I automatically get images of specific areas of a video frame every second? I'm using python ffmpeg and opencv right now but open to other technologies. Attached picture for example of what areas of the frame I want to get.

[image]

Comment: if you know coordinates for regions then you can get frame and cut off using [pillow.Image.crop](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop). If you have frame from `openCV` then you have `numpy.array` and you can slice it `frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Comment: Just inspire yourself from code like this which iterates over frames in video https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/df8/tutorial_py_meanshift.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass the co-ordinates of the targeted area in the frame in the code below

```
image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

The code is

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0

while success:

        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.png" % count, image[1020:1150,370:500]) 
        success, image = vidcap.read()

        print('Read a new frame: ', success)
        count += 1
```